# Android: Dynamically inserting view results in change in colors of form widgets

Tags: android, view, colors, widget

In my Android activity I attempt to dynamically add a view inside my existing view.

I do so with the following code:

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.newactivity_name, null);
View insertPoint = findViewById(R.id.aVerticalLinearLayout);
((ViewGroup) insertPoint).addView(v, 0, new  ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Everything seems to work fine except somehow the colors/theme get messed up
making all the form widgets seem extremely faded.

How I expect it to look:
[How it is displayed in the xml graphic display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qim1V.png)

How it looks:
[how it appears on the emulator after being inflated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAx3C.png)  (ignore the text:hint being different)

Any ideas?

Or could you tell me how I can make the calenderView and DatePicker look normal by manually
setting the colors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the parent when inflating the view so that it gets the styling and theme from the parent view.

```
LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View insertPoint = findViewById(R.id.aVerticalLinearLayout);
View v = vi.inflate(R.layout.newactivity_name, insertPoint); <-----
((ViewGroup) insertPoint).addView(v, 0, new  ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

Comment: What ended up solving the problem for a reason I do not fully understand at the momment is using simply      View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_reminder, insertPoint,false); instead of having the LayoutInflater as its own variable.